# Find the age of the oldest file in one line

Tags: linux, files, date, stat

I tried

```bsh
stat -c %Y ./* 2>/dev/null | awk -v d="$(date +%s)" 'BEGIN {m=d} $0 < m {m = $0} END {print d - m}'
```

to find the age of the oldest file in the current directory, and I get a number in seconds with this line.

How do I get a number in *days* in that one line? Thank you

Comment: Can't you just use `days=seconds/(24*60*60)`

Comment: why go through all the trouble?  ```ls -t1 | tail -1``` will give you the oldest file by modification date.  Then you can ```stat -c %Y``` that file to get the number of seconds.  Divide by 86400 (seconds in a day) to get days.  In one line it would be something like ```echo `stat -c %Y \`ls -t1 | tail -1\``/86400 | bc | tr -d '\n';echo " days"```

Comment: @Fubar `ls` will break badly if the names have spaces or glob characters or newlines. See [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)

Comment: if you're worried about garbage filenames, put quotes around the name?  ```file=`ls -t1 | tail -1`;echo `stat -c %Y "$file"`/86400 | bc | tr -d '\n';echo " days"```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken this solution should also work to print the oldest age in days`without using complicated constructs:

```
echo "$(( ($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y ./* | sort -n | head -n 1)) / 86400 )) days"
```

and to answer your question - just wrap it for the calculation:

```
echo $(( $(stat -c %Y ./* 2>/dev/null | awk -v d="$(date +%s)" 'BEGIN {m=d} $0 < m {m = $0} END {print d - m}') /86400 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` and `zsh`:

```
$ ls -ld ./*(D-Om[1])
-rw-r--r-- 1 stephane stephane 205 Jan 11  2004 ./Y2K
$ perl -le 'print -M shift' ./*(D-Om[1])
5947.59262731482
```

With `zsh` alone and with nanosecond precision (limited by the precision of your compiler's `double`s):

```
zmodload zsh/datetime zsh/stat
stat -F %s.%N -A t +mtime ./*(D-Om[1]) &&
  print $(((EPOCHREALTIME - t) / 24 / 60 / 60))
```

(note that a *day* in that case is a 86400 Unix second unit)